# Pegar meta-data do AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

Estou desenvolvendo uma biblioteca.

Para utilização o desenvolvedor deverá informar uma chave de uso.

Gostaria de utilizar a mesma forma que o Google maps:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Existe alguma forma de eu pegar esta informação de dentro do `AndroidManifest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obter a informação declarada no elemento [meta-data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html) use o campo [metaData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#metaData) da classe [PackageItemInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html).

Se tiver a seguinte `<meta-data>`

```
<meta-data android:name="api_key" android:value="chave123" />
```

o código seguinte colocará na String `apiKey` o valor `"chave123"`

```
try {
    PackageItemInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(),
                                                             PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    Bundle bundle = packageInfo.metaData;
    String apiKey = bundle.getString("api_key");
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("MetaData", "Erro ao ler meta-data, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e("MetaData", "Erro ao ler meta-data, NullPointer: " + e.getMessage());
}
```